# Queries in Laravel Logic operators

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I want to query Laravel DB for something like

```
SELECT * FROM `tickets` 
WHERE (created_at > '2015-07-01'
    AND created_at < '2015-07-31')
AND (state != 'Resolved'
    OR state != 'closed'
    OR state != 'Cancelled'
    OR state != 'Solution Rejected')
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

I tried using raw statements but doesn't seem to work. So I'm trying to use Laravel's own model functions to archive the same result, but I'm missing something... here's what I got so far.

```
Ticket::whereBetween('created_at', [$start, $end])
->whereIn('state',['Resolved','closed','Cancelled','Solution Rejected'])
->get();
```

PS: alternatively is there a way I can have this instead

```
SELECT * FROM `tickets` 
WHERE ( (created_at > '2015-07-01'
    AND created_at < '2015-07-31')
    OR (updated_at > '2015-07-01'
    AND updated_at < '2015-07-31') )
AND (state != 'Resolved'
    OR state != 'closed'
    OR state != 'Cancelled'
    OR state != 'Solution Rejected')
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Comment: `state != 'Resolved' OR state != 'closed' ...` will always be true becuase `state` can't have multiple values at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Try this one sir:

```
  DB::table('tickets')
        ->whereBetween('created_at',[$start, $end])
        ->orWhere(function($query)
        {
            $query->where('state', '!=', 'Resolved')
                  ->where('state', '!=', 'closed')
                  ->where('state', '!=', 'Cancelled')
                  ->where('state', '!=', 'Solution Rejected')
                  ->orderBy('id', 'desc');
        })
        ->get();
```

Comment: Try again sir. Sorry Double ")"

Comment: yeah I fixed that... It works as in it brings out results but I think it's not working logically as I want it. I think it's showing the dates OR not the states. But I need to double check. My hint is that a query that shouldn't return any results actually returned so many that the server timed out